# Vertices presenting weird behaviour when moving armature

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have a long cylinder with three bones assigned to it, all works well, except for a single edge loop right in the middle of it. It stays exactly the same no matter the weights it has painted on, or the position it is in; scaling, moving, deforming the edge, does change anything, and removing it just passes the same behaviour to the next one over. This repeats itself over three other copies of said cylinder.

I'm using *Blender 2.8*, the only modifier my mesh has is an AutoSmooth, I've checked multiple times and there's no other bones attached to any of those vertex groups. Google doesn't seem to help.

As you can see, there's a weird edge/bump right in the middle of every bent limb.
[image: Mat mesh]

And no matter the weights painted on, it doesn't change even a bit; not even  when the surrounding vertices have the exact same weight.
[image: Weights 1]
[image: Weights 2]
[image: Weights 3]

And the mesh and bones seem perfectly fine too. I have no idea what I'm missing...
[image: Wireframe]

Here's the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LAai3-xQAObKu2yIYvjRS_6C3QAwwd9Z/view?usp=sharing), in case you wanna dissect it.

Thanks in advance for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)